# ExitNodes doesn't seem to work Jordan {JO}

Tags: configuration, exit-policies

I wanted to change my `torrc` file so the `ExitNodes` is Jordan {JO}. When I did that, the Tor Browser couldn't connect.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are no Jordanian exit nodes currently listed:

https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/country:jo%20flag:exit

Unless you can find one somehow that's miscategorized as being located elsewhere, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: So how can i make an ExitNodes in Jordan